# Wordpress: how to use custom CSS to align logo with adjacent text and tagline

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am helping a colleague with new Wordpress site. She has purchased a theme, Hive and we are trying to position a logo and line it up with text to the right. This, so far has been successful however we want to have a "minor tagline" underneath the main title

I have been modifying the CSS but I don't think I can modify the HTML. The problem I am finding is trying to position the tagline underneath the main title. I have been using flex-box with some success but please see the image which describes the problem better than I can explain it.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Everything is contained in a "site-branding". I thought I could add a line break or a  create another line below "The Weld Hotwire" but you cannot alter the HTML.

Please see the CSS to the left.

I fully understand that this is an unusual manner to pose a question but would be really grateful for any guidance on how to get the tagline "Engineering, Society, Policy" on its own line below the main title.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You likely need to use a `grid` instead of a `flexbox`, but it's hard to tell because not all of your code is visible.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find it fast, please go save it and open in chrome/firefox.
and go developer tools with detect it very fast.

find 'right class or id' with inspect and make your changes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N510.png